# Are HTML entity codes dependant on the operating system or the browser?

Tags: html, html-entities

Im using HTML entity codes to display first, previous, next and last in my pagination script.

```
<span style="font-size:35px">&#8678;</span>First
<span style="font-size:35px">&#8882;</span>Prev
<span style="font-size:35px">&#8883;</span>Next
<span style="font-size:35px">&#8680;</span>Last
```

It shows correctly on my Ubuntu system.

[image: linux]

But on Windows, prev and next are reversed.

[image: windows]

According to [W3](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref), 
its `&vltri; &vartriangleleft; &LeftTriangle;` and `&vrtri; &vartriangleright; &RightTriangle;`

Answer (score 0):

**No**

its a core part of HTML language so every browser and OS support these characters. for example you have seen Copyright character in all website in all browsers and OS.
if any dependency exist is HTML language version. may be **HTML-4 is supporting less** and **HTML-5 supports more**.